# Case Statement for sum of multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

So I am working on creating a payroll import file for our accounting department and I am having trouble calculating overtime properly in my report.

Here is my query

```
declare @week1start date
declare @week1end date
declare @week2start date
declare @week2end date

--Week 1 Start and End
set @week1start = CAST('10/15/2018' as date)
set @week1end = CAST('10/21/2018' as date)

--Week 2 Start and End
set @week2start = CAST('10/22/2018' as date)
set @week2end = CAST('10/28/2018' as date)

--Week 1 Hours Worked

(select Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM as [Employee Num],Employee.NAME as [Employee Name],Time_Clk.StoreNumber as [Store],

[Week 1 Hours Worked]= case
when (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) - 40 > 0
then 40
else (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2))))
end,

[Week 1 OT Hours] = case
when (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) - 40 > 0
then (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) -40
else 0
end,
0 as [Week 2 Hours Worked],
0 as [Week 2 OT Hours]

from Time_Clk
join Employee on Time_Clk.EMPLOYEE_ID = Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM

where CAST(out_time as DATE) >= @week1start and CAST(out_time as date) <= @week1end and Time_Clk.OUT_TYPE = 1

group by Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM,Employee.NAME,Time_Clk.StoreNumber)

union all

--Week 2 hours worked

(select Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM as [Employee Num],Employee.NAME as [Employee Name],Time_Clk.StoreNumber as [Store],

0 as [Week 1 Hours Worked],
0 as [Week 1 OT Hours],

[Week 2 Hours Worked] = case
when (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) - 40 > 0
then 40
else (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2))))
end,

[Week 2 OT Hours] = case
when (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) - 40 > 0
then (sum(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME) as decimal (10,2))/60 as decimal (10,2)))) -40
else 0
end

from Time_Clk
join Employee on Time_Clk.EMPLOYEE_ID = Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM

where CAST(out_time as DATE) >= @week2start and CAST(out_time as date) <= @week2end and Time_Clk.OUT_TYPE = 1

group by Employee.EMPLOYEE_NUM,Employee.NAME,Time_Clk.StoreNumber)

order by [Employee Num]
```

So most of my output is fine but here is a select output for a particular user

```
 EmpNum EmpName  Store  Week 1 Hrs  Week 1 OT   Week 2 Hours    Week 2 OT 
    1   Name    1       0.00        0.00          40.00         0.88
    1   Name    1       39.20       0.00          0.00          0.00
    1   Name    2       5.23        0.00          0.00         0.00
```

So in the problem that I am facing is that Week 1 technically has overtime hours because they worked more than 40 hours that week, but at two different locations. Ideally the result would look like

```
EmpNum  EmpName  Store  Week 1 Hrs  Week 1 OT   Week 2 Hours    Week 2 OT 
    1   Name    1       0.00        0.00          40.00         0.88
    1   Name    1       39.20       0.00          0.00          0.00
    1   Name    2       0.80        4.43          0.00         0.00
```

I considered doing a case statement but to determine that the person had a total over 40 hours between all 3 lines in week 1, but I dont believe I can do that with the way the data is.

Hopefully all of the formatting comes through ok, I am new to posting on these forums.

Comment: I think using a sub query and maybe a temp table with middle results could be helpful and easier to read.  Do all your calculations in the sub query and then do your case statements on the calculated values instead of redoing the calculations multiple times.

Comment: Wouldnt I still have the same issue even with a temp table? I have to retain the store location because of where the pay gets coded. The only way I can get a total hours for that week would be to remove the location information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using only start and end date for the total period all weeks.
If given start date is always period begin date you can compute week number and group hours by resulting week number. You can use datepart or just mod 7 (%) if you use some fiscal calendar.

Once you have that in a vertical form you can do some pivoting magic to get the result you are looking for.

maybe something like this...

```
if object_id('employee') is not null drop table employee
if object_id('timeclock') is not null drop table timeclock
Go

CREATE TABLE employee (employeeid int identity(1,1), name varchar(50)) ;
GO
CREATE TABLE timeclock (id int identity(1,1), employeeid int, IN_TIME datetime, OUT_TIME datetime);
Go
insert into employee
  (name) 
 values (CHAR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%26+65))
GO 5

;WITH [days] AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS [day]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [day]+1
        FROM [days] 
        WHERE [day] < 20

)
INSERT INTO timeclock
Select employeeid, GetDate()+[day], Dateadd(hh,8, GETDATE()+[day])
from employee
CROSS APPLY [days]


declare @start datetime = '11/12/2018';
declare @end datetime = @start + 15



;with aggregatedata
as
(
    select 
        employee.employeeid
        , employee.name
        ,weeknum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by employee.employeeid order by employee.employeeid, DATEPART(week, In_time) )
        ,[hours] = sum(DATEDIFF(Minute,IN_TIME,OUT_TIME)) 
    from employee
        inner join timeclock on employee.employeeid = timeclock.employeeid
    WHERE
        in_time > @start and OUT_TIME < @end
    group by employee.employeeid, employee.name, DATEPART(week, In_time)
)

select
    employeeid, [name], [1], [2], [3], [4]
from aggregatedata
PIVOT 
(
    sum([hours])
    for weeknum in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `Time_Clk.StoreNumber` from your `SELECT` and from the `GROUP BY`, then you would get the results you are after. If accounting is using this to determine what accounts to charge to, then naturally you have to keep it in. In that case, you may want to use a window function.

```
sum(<your statement>) over (partition by EmpNum)
```

But this would place the value in both store 1 and store 2 row.

Sample data would really make this easier.